# common.apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException: No content to map to Object due to end of input

Tags: apex, integration

I have below code. I am making two requests for different objects. FOr first request , I am getting data but for second request, I am getting:

> 'common.apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException: No content to map to Object due to end of input'

```
public with sharing class SearchAcctFromSf {  
    public String pwd{get;set;}
    public String userName{get;set;}
    public List<Product_Component__c> acc{get;set;}
    public List<Product_Detail__c> prodDetail{get;set;}
    public String errMsg{get;set;}
    public String displayError{get;set;}

    public SearchAcctFromSf() {
        displayError = 'none';
    }

    public void fetch() {
        errMsg  = 'Some error occurred, please try again';
        try {
        /*-----------------------------------
         Login via SOAP/XML web service api
        -----------------------------------*/
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint('https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/39.0');
        request.setMethod('POST');
        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8');
        request.setHeader('SOAPAction', '""');
        /*not escaping username and password because we're setting those variables above
        in other words, this line "trusts" the lines above
        if username and password were sourced elsewhere, they'd need to be escaped below*/
        request.setBody('<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><Header/><Body><login xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com"><username>' + userName+ '</username><password>' + pwd+ '</password></login></Body></Envelope>');
        Dom.XmlNode resultElmt = (new Http()).send(request).getBodyDocument().getRootElement()
          .getChildElement('Body', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/')
          .getChildElement('loginResponse', 'urn:partner.soap.sforce.com')
          .getChildElement('result', 'urn:partner.soap.sforce.com');

        /*-------------------------------
         Grab session id and server url
        --------------------------------*/
        final String SERVER_URL = resultElmt.getChildElement('serverUrl', 'urn:partner.soap.sforce.com') .getText().split('/services')[0];
        final String SESSION_ID = resultElmt.getChildElement('sessionId', 'urn:partner.soap.sforce.com') .getText();
        system.debug('SESSION_ID+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++'+SERVER_URL);
        /*----------------------------------
         Load first 20 accounts via REST API
        ---------------------------------*/
        final PageReference theUrl = new PageReference(SERVER_URL + '/services/data/v39.0/query/');
        theUrl.getParameters().put('q','Select a.Id, a.Name, a.Asset_Name__c,a.Functional_Code__c,a.StagingID__c From Product_Component__c a');
        request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint(theUrl.getUrl());
        request.setMethod('GET');
        request.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + SESSION_ID);

        String body = (new Http()).send(request).getBody();

        JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(body);

        do {
            parser.nextToken();
        }
        while(parser.hasCurrentToken() && !'records'.equals(parser.getCurrentName()));

        parser.nextToken();
        system.debug('Before prodDetail**********************************'+parser);
        acc = (List<Product_Component__c>) parser.readValueAs(List<Product_Component__c>.class);



       /****************************************************************************************************************************************************************/

       HttpRequest request2 = new HttpRequest();
        request2.setEndpoint('https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/39.0');
        request2.setMethod('POST');
        request2.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8');
        request2.setHeader('SOAPAction', '""');
        /*not escaping username and password because we're setting those variables above
        in other words, this line "trusts" the lines above
        if username and password were sourced elsewhere, they'd need to be escaped below*/
        request2.setBody('<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><Header/><Body><login xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com"><username>' + userName+ '</username><password>' + pwd+ '</password></login></Body></Envelope>');
        Dom.XmlNode resultElmt2 = (new Http()).send(request2).getBodyDocument().getRootElement()
          .getChildElement('Body', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/')
          .getChildElement('loginResponse', 'urn:partner.soap.sforce.com')
          .getChildElement('result', 'urn:partner.soap.sforce.com');


        final PageReference theUrl2 = new PageReference(SERVER_URL + '/services/data/v39.0/query/');
        theUrl2.getParameters().put('q2','Select a.Id, a.Name, a.Asset_Name__c,a.Product__c,a.Product_Component__c From Product_Detail__c a');
        //request2 = new HttpRequest();
        request2.setEndpoint(theUrl2.getUrl());
        request2.setMethod('GET');
        request2.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + SESSION_ID);

        string body2 = (new Http()).send(request2).getBody();

        JSONParser parser2 = JSON.createParser(body2);

        do {
            parser2.nextToken();
        }
        while(parser2.hasCurrentToken() && !'records'.equals(parser2.getCurrentName()));

        parser2.nextToken();
        system.debug('Before prodDetail**********************************'+parser2);
        prodDetail = (List<Product_Detail__c>) parser2.readValueAs(List<Product_Detail__c>.class);
         system.debug('prodDetail**********************************'+prodDetail);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.WARNING,errMsg));

            displayError = 'block';
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You are most likely getting an error response from the server. You should be checking status codes instead of blindly getting and attempting to parse a body of a response that may not contain what you are looking for

Comment: I go with Eric, the response is what is screwing up . Mostly you might get raw HTML response (or) some unparsable response . Check for the specific codes and then parse the response